# webhook bot in docker container

Tags: docker, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I deploy my application using docker, and I have django-app and a telegram bot (webhook) in the same container, how can I make my webhook work? (attached screenshots)

This is what I get when I run the bot without docker, it's correct and it works:

```
* Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
* Running on https://127.0.0.1:8443
* Running on https://81.87.198.222:8443 (Press CTRL+C to quit) and etc...
```

With docker:

```
* Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
* Running on https://127.0.0.1:8443
* Running on https://172.19.0.3:8443 (Press CTRL+C to quit) and etc...
```

I understand that my webhook should be given to the white address, but in the case of docker, I have the address of the docker container, but how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 8443 port need to be exposed onto the host, using `-p 8443: 8443` on docker run command, or

```
ports:
  - 8443:8443
```

on docker-compose manifest.

PS: Also I would advise having a container for each processes, but as long as it works.

Answer (score -1):

Run your `docker run` command with `--network=host`